# Button per line in Custom Post Types

Tags: custom-post-types

Since several hours ago I am trying to solve this issue but I don't know what I am doing wrong in the code.

I have a Custom Post Type with several records, then I wrote a php script to show the content as a table:

[image: Query Table]

At the end of each row there is a button, the idea is to pass the row's POST_ID value to other form and php script. However, after you click this button, it opens a new tab with the URL including the name of the site and Post_ID value like `https://telework/wp-admin/admin.php?Id=2749&submit_btn=Pagar`.

The button's code is:

```
<td> <form type="post"><input type="hidden" name="Id" value="<?php echo $post_id; ?>"><input type="submit" name="submit_btn" value="Pagar"></form></td>
```

I've tried to insert `action="process.php"` inside `<form>`, then change the `type="post"` to `method="post"` but gives me error 500.

How and where can I include the code to open the new form and php script?
Thank you for your help and have a good day.

Marcelo

Answer (score 0):

Anybody have this similar issue, please read this info at  https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/handling-form-submissions/, this helps me a lot.